# Как реализовать стрелку между блоками, которая будет соединять их при любой ширине/высоте экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Есть следующая задачка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стрелочка должна соединять блоки вне зависимости от их месторасположения и быть изогнутой. Нашел решение с помощью `jquery`, но хотелось бы реализовать на `js`. Предполагаю, что вопрос можно решить с помощью кривых Безье, где первая и последняя точки будут координатами блоков, но тема для меня новая, может быть есть другой, более простой способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Универсальное решение, вероятно, будет непростым, если нужно учитывать, к какому месту прямоугольника цепляться, обходить ли другие блоки и т.д.

Для простого случая предложу рисовать дугу в четверть эллипса.
Для начальной точки x0, y0 и конечной x1,y1:
Сначала M в x0,y0, потом A
Дуга в SVG описывается как:

```
A rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y
```

здесь

```
 rx = Math.abs(x1-x0)
 ry = Math.abs(y1-y0)
 x-axis-rotation = 0
 large-arc-flag = 0
 sweep-flag = 0 или 1
 x = x1
 y = y1
```

sweep-flag выбирается в зависимости от того, по часовой стрелке или против нее должна идти дуга, а этот выбор зависит от расположения блоков (в какое ребро должна входить дуга - в вертикальное или горизонтальное)

Вариант с кривой Безье c горизонтальным началом и вертикальным концом:

```
  M x0 y0 C (x0 + x1)/2 y0 x1 (y0 + y1)/2 x1 y1
```